# Prevent mpv from opening maximised

Tags: multimedia, video-player, media, mpv-media-player

Is there a setting I can add to `~/.config/mpv/scripts` to prevent mpv from opening in a maximised window?

Comment: check out **[--geometry](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-geometry)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## don't allow a new window to have a size larger than 90% of the screen size

autofit-larger=90%x90%

taken from https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/etc/mpv.conf

Answer (score 0):

You can specify window geometry with

```
--geometry=1024x768+0+0
```

This will stick the window in the top left corner, with a size of 1024x768